# gdb generate-core-file makes corrupted coredumps

Tags: gdb, coredump

Ubuntu 10.10, GDB 7.2.
I attach to an application, watch stacks in every thread, everything looks good. Do generate-core-file and try to open that coredump in gdb. No routines is shown in backtraces.

I send SIGSEGV to the application and open this new coredump in gdb. Stacks are ok and verbose.

Please tell me if you experienced a similar incorrect behaviour of generate-core-file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is a known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdb/+bug/680588) in GDB. The link has also a patch for fixing the problem.

Comment: FYI, for anyone building gdb from source, here's the corresponding bug from Ubuntu 12.04 beta with the patch updated for gdb 7.4+: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdb/+bug/954714